# Align* in mhchem that also has some $math$ content in it?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, mhchem

Here is an mwe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \ce{ A &-> B } \\ 
  \ce{ C + E &-> Prod } 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The above works perfectly fine giving me the output - [image]

However when I am adding some math content here like so

```
\begin{align*}
  \ce{ A &-> B } $ \Delta H = x $ \\
  \ce{ C + E &-> Prod } $ \Delta H = y $ 
\end{align*}
```

The compilation fails. giving me just - [image]

Can anyone point out what am i doing wrong?

The error it shows is - `added a missing }` and then  `added a $` etc etc.

Comment: Have you tried putting "&" outside the \ce command? Divide reactions into parts if necessary.

Comment: What are those `$` doing in math mode? Remove the `$`'s and it compiles just fine.

Comment: @daleif , i did not know align already types in mathmode. removing the ```$``` makes it compile perfectly!

Comment: Then, if you are a novice I'd suggest you read any proper introduction to math in LaTeX. The environments from `amsmath` is the golden standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align` typesets its contents in math mode, so the `$` characters are wrong.

Perhaps you also want a further alignment point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \ce{ A &-> B }        & \Delta H &= x\\
  \ce{ C + E &-> Prod } & \Delta H &= y
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \ce{ A &-> B }        &\qquad \Delta H &= x\\
  \ce{ C + E &-> Prod } &       \Delta H &= y
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. It solved my issue. I did look at the difference between ```align``` and ```alignat``` from your other answer. it seems like i can use either depending on the output /spacing that i like better.